# Scala.js with Karaf

Tags: scala.js, karaf

I want to serve out a Scala.js application from OSGi/Karaf Jetty.
It appears to me this could be done by packaging the Scala.js application as a WAR file.

Or is there maybe a better way?

Comment: There's an [interesting thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/scala-js/war|sort:relevance/scala-js/UjtCW-HflQI/C8-ER7bbBwAJ) on the Scala.js Google Group.

Answer (score 1):

Scala.js compiled files could be published as static assets, since it is Javascript in the end.